# compare and merge array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const arr1 = [{id:1, checked:false},{id:2, checked:false},{id:3, checked:false}]

const arr2 = [{id:1},{id:3}]
```

i have 2 arrays like above. i want to result should be

```
arr1 = [{id:1, checked:true},{id:2, checked:false},{id:3, checked:true}]
```

i tried with array filter, but it gives joined array

```
companyArr.forEach(citem => {
        mapItem.forEach(mitem => {
            companyArr.push({
            Id: citem.Id,
            CompanyName: citem.CompanyName,
            isChecked: (mitem.company_id === citem.Id)
          })
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which keeps all your ids from each object in `arr2`, and then use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `arr1` to check the `checked` values based on whether the set has the current objects id:

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1, checked:false},{id:2, checked:false},{id:3, checked:false}]
const arr2 = [{id:1},{id:3}];

const lut = new Set(arr2.map(({id}) => id));
const res = arr1.map(o => ({...o, checked: lut.has(o.id)}))
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore */
```

**Note:** I've created a set here for efficient lookup, however, you could use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on arr2 if you wish in the `.map()` as well, but this would have performance drawbacks for large data sets:

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1, checked:false},{id:2, checked:false},{id:3, checked:false}]
const arr2 = [{id:1},{id:3}];

const res = arr1.map(o => ({...o, checked: arr2.some(({id}) => id === o.id)}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore */
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Array#map` for recreate the array .And `Array#findIndex` for find the first array value exist on 2nd array .And use [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for easy to split the object

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1, checked:false},{id:2, checked:false},{id:3, checked:false}]
const arr2 = [{id:1},{id:3}]

let res =  arr1.map(a=> ({...a,checked: arr2.findIndex(({id}) => id == a.id) > -1}));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `find` for that.

```js
const arr1 = [{ id: 1, checked: false }, { id: 2, checked: false }, { id: 3, checked: false }]
  , arr2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 3 }]
  , result = arr1.map(el => ({ ...el, checked: !!arr2.find(({ id }) => id === el.id) }));

console.log(result);
```